# Given a function and its variables' types, how to get the type of the return value?

Tags: typescript, function, typescript-generics

Say we have this example:

```js
const a = 'Hello' as const 
function f(){
    return a[0]
} 
const b = f()
```

The type of `b` is `string`, not `'H'`. Is there a way to make it so? In practice, I want something like this:

```js
type A = 'Hello'
type B = f(A)
```

So that if I need to change `A`, I don't need to change `B` too. I read about [`Generics`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) but still don't know how to apply it. Getting first character in the string is just an example. The input variables can be arrays, objects, etc.

Comment: This is because of a TS weakness in its out of the box inference for string manipulation. It is unable to infer `"a string"[n]` is a specific character. You might be interested in https://github.com/gustavoguichard/string-ts?tab=readme-ov-file#charat and its impl https://github.com/gustavoguichard/string-ts/blob/1fc01e9646971056407bf35e3b7258eaffd06526/src/native/char-at.ts#L13

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on "TS weakness in its default typings"? Also, this library seems to limit on string manipulation. If the input is not a string then a general function is better I think

Comment: • Your question title is really vague (generic types like `type F<T> = ...T...` is the answer to that). Could you [edit] to make it specific?

Comment: (see prev comment) • The question seems to be asking about two separate things. One is: if I have a function `f` and an argument `x`, can I represent `typeof f(x)`? That is a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179). The other is: "how can I index into strings at the type level"? And that is a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#41037](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41037). Which one do you care about (and it really should be just one, not both)? Please [edit] to make that clear.

Comment: @jcalz the first one. I have edited it. Is that clearer? I thought the latter feature is a specific case of the former?

Comment: It's clearer but then the part about `"H"` is a red herring, since the type of the return is `string`, as you said. If you're not asking about getting `"H"` then remove that part.  You should write a function where the return type is what you want it to be, and then we can explore how to write a type that extracts that return type, mentioning ms/TS#40179. ---- you edited your comment: no, indexing into strings is not a specific case of representing return types.